# Choppy uwp video playback on pi3

Tags: pi-3, windows-iot

Video playback through a simple `MediaPlayerElement` UWP control to play a video file from local storage results in very choppy playback. At 1920x1080, the video will barely render and at 640x480 it is still too choppy to be useful.

Is this expected or does it sound like I have a problem with my environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=105&t=154265) and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/64d2ef26-a844-4210-bbbf-50014324cb4d/gpu-accelleration?forum=WindowsIoT) GPU acceleration is not available on Windows 10 IoT for RPi :(

Might want to consider using raspbian if possible. If you find the playback is still choppy on Raspbian for FullHD, You could try increasing the [amount of memory](http://elinux.org/RPiconfig#Memory) allocated to the GPU using `raspi-config` and checking if that improves the performance.

the following commands should tell you how much is currently allocated

- `vcgencmd get_mem arm`
- `vcgencmd get_mem gpu`

Comment: This seems correct, but it makes me have so many sad faces.

Comment: They working on a compatible DirectX driver... but it taking longer than expected. https://github.com/Microsoft/graphics-driver-samples/tree/master/render-only-sample - Some demos there but I cannot see anything about streaming h264 vide